# Use Laurent series to evaluate

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Use Laurent series to evaluate $\int_{|z|=2}dz/(4z-z^2)$. I've proved that $1/(4z-z^2)=1/4z+\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/4^{n+2}$. And I know the following formula:
[image]

Is the answer to this integration: $ln(2)/2+2\pi i/64$?

Comment: Think about using the residues. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: Wait.. I think the second part is equal to $1/16\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/4^n$? Then we can apply the formula to it.

Comment: $$2\pi i \times \frac14=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: So what if it is $\sum z^n/4^n$, would the answer be the same?

Comment: For my series I got $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}} $ And so when we integrate, we see that all the terms where $n>0$ will integrate to 0 from Cauchy's integral theorem. Thus, we are left with $2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{\pi i}{2}$

Comment: You have a sum  $\;\frac1{4z}+\ldots\;$ where you must a product $\;\frac1{4z}\cdot\sum...\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspection, the only pole of the function relevant in $\;|z|\le2\;$ is zero, so we need a Laurent series in an annulus of the form $\;0<|z|<r\le2\;$ :

$$\frac1{4z-z^2}=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{4-z}=\frac1{4z}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac z4}\stackrel{\text{Why can we?}}=\frac1{4z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{4^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}}\implies$$

$$\implies a_{-1}\stackrel{\text{with}\;n=0\;}=\frac14$$

and then

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{4z-z^2}=2\pi i\cdot\frac14=\frac{\pi i}2$$